# Topology causing Subdivision surface and Solidify problems

Tags: modifiers, subdivision-surface, topology, bevel, solidify-modifier

In short this is probably bad Topology causing Subdivision surface not to work as expected, and also create unknown problems for Solidify modifier.

[image]

### Problem 1

I'm very new in Blender, I'm trying to make an old lock to improve my skill. I use "Subdivision surface" to mimic the round button and add "Bevel" to give its edge finish. It looks fine from outside, but inside the raised part it seems "Subdivision surface" can't find enough geometry. Its corner and edge doesn't look right. I may need to improve the topology according to other people's post, what should I change in the topology? I try to Bevel this part myself but it affects the Bevel modifier to round other parts.

[image](reference picture find on internet)

[image](model without modifier)

[image](after Bevel + Subdivision surface)

[image]
(Subdivision surface create unwanted surface at inside corner, the edge gets bend to curve, and the shape of hole doesn't connect correctly. lack of clear geometry according to other people's post questions.)

### Problem 2 - Unknown problem about Solidify result

Caused by Problem 1, I guess.

I add "Solidify" to make thickness, but as the picture show below, some strange thing is sticking out of my model. why this happen?

[image]

[image: Edit according to comment](Edit after posting according to comment)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You should put the Solidify above the Subdivision Surface. The rest seems to work as expected. For the base of your shape that is smoothed it is normal considering your topology. If you are a beginner maybe you should not work with modifiers like Bevel but instead create real bevels, you would understand better how it works?

Comment: Sorry, I try to put the Solidify above the Subdivision Surface, but the plate become rounded on every edge now. It now lose the iron plate edge cut place.

Comment: I will try Bevel myself later, I often regret on the bevel result and need to redo the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on *Face Orientation* in the *Overlays* menu so you can see the problem.

[image]

Notice that when the *Bevel Amount* exceeds $0.0074m$ it becomes problematic because it goes beyond geometry boundaries. Your bevel is at $0.01m$ which is way beyond the limit for your particular mesh.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, I now see there are multiple red dots appearing at certain angles around the model. I will adjust these overlaps from beyond bevels.